# How to Creat a Session which shows the user name of the user when a person logs in with email and password

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a login form which has the email and a password but i want it 
  show the user name instead of email on the next page as logged in e.g 
   welcome "samuel". how do i apply sessions.

I have tried to create sessions name but it does not accept.
What i can i do in order to have a suucefull username displayed without having to include a user name input text box on the login form

```
   session_start();
```

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

```
           $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
            $password = 
              mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
           $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['mobile']);

       if (empty($email or $mobile)) {
        array_push($errors, "Email Or mobile number is required");
           }
        if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
      }
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
          $query = "SELECT * FROM farmers WHERE (email='$email' OR 
           mobile='$mobile') AND password='$password'";
           $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){


        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $email=$_SESSION['username'];
        $_SESSION['sucess'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: account_activation.php');//redirect to 
       survey
        }else{

        array_push($errors, "Wrong email/Mobile number or 
         Password combination");

         }

         }

         }





   //account_activation.php
   <?php include('server.php');

     if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
   header('location: login.php');
     }
   ?>

      <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
      scale=1, 
   shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Account Activation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 


    </style>

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="survey.css">
   </head>
      <body>
   <div class="header">
    <h2>Account activation</h2>
    </div>
     <div class="content">
     <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])):?>
        <div class="error success">
        <h3>
            <?php
            echo $_SESSION['success'];
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
              ?>
        </h3>

         </div>

        <?php endif ?>
       <?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"])): ?>
       <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong> 
      </p>
       <p><a href="survey.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">LogOut</a> 
      </p>
       <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: pretty simple to get working and a google search could have solved this. $_SESSION['name'] = $result['name']; Please atleast try something before you post on stack ...

Comment: could you please give me details of how i should implement

Comment: Have you removed the code? please put it back because i was still following it

Comment: It's back. I remouved it because i got downvoted for some reason

Comment: Sir i have name not username in my database.

Comment: You can change that to the right col. You did not share the table with us so there no way to know on my end lol

Comment: It doesnot show the welcome name and logout when i corrected according to your code

Comment: let me check again

Comment: $sql = $db->query("SELECT id, name, password, isEmailConfirmed FROM farmers WHERE email='$email' OR mobile='$mobile'");

Comment: that is the query i used

Comment: try the code again. As for the query, where did you put that in your code?

Comment: By the way, i assumed the session_start(); was inside server.php in the account_activation.php page. if it's not you will need to start with that for the sessions to be created. It needs to be the first thing the PHP page does in every page of the website. The best way of doing that is by putting it in a global file that is included everywhere.

Comment: Hey you,you are the best, you have saved me please!!!! it worked. form thwe code you posted, i moved this  ?>
            <p>Welcome <strong><?= $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong> </p>
            <p><a href="survey.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">LogOut</a> </p>
            <?php into if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])):

Comment: my pleasure. please up vote the awnser :-) next time show us what you tryed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['mobile']);

    if (empty($email) || empty($mobile)) {
        array_push($errors, "Email Or mobile number is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM farmers WHERE (email='$email' OR mobile='$mobile') AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            $_SESSION['email'] = $result['email'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
            header('location: account_activation.php'); //redirect to survey

        } else {

            array_push($errors, "Wrong email/Mobile number or Password combination");

        }

    }

}

?>



//account_activation.php
<?php
include ('server.php');

if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != "1") {
    header('location: login.php');
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <title>Account Activation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="survey.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Account activation</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])):
            ?>
            <div class="error success">
                <h3>You're logged in</h3>
            </div>

            <?php
        endif;
        ?>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["username"])):
            ?>
            <p>Welcome <strong><?= $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong> </p>
            <p><a href="survey.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">LogOut</a> </p>
            <?php
        endif;
        ?>
```

To retreive the username from the table you need to use this: $result['username'];
(Assuming theres a column named username in the farmers table.)

To echo the username, use short tags (Needs to be enabled in the php.ini)

Don't forget to exit() after a header redirect. A hacker can block the request to redirect and see the page under. Always block execution. It's also faster since the server is not loading the full page.

Also I noticed a PHP error

```
if (empty($email or $mobile))
```

should be

```
if (empty($email) || empty($mobile))
```

You had a few HTML mistakes as well. Self closed HTML tags should be closed like so:

```
<meta name="description" content=""/>
```

Notice the / at the end.

One last comment ... Your identation is horible... This is a very bad habit. You're clearly starting with coding and you should really put in some effort.

This question of yours could have been solved by googling "How to retreive data from MySQL using mysqli_query()".

Stack is not a website where we do the work for you. If you post a question, make sure you show what you tryed and what the problem is. "How do you do this" with out providing the code of what you tryed does not qualify on this website. In any case, good luck on your journey!